# Wowza error Not licensed for HTTPOrigin mode

Tags: wowza

I am trying to use Wowza for RTMP streaming using FMLE as encoder.
When I start the stream from FMLE then in logs of Wowza i see below errors:

```
[xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:x][ServerHandler.71][com.wowza.wms.logging.WMSLogger:log] WARN - HTTPStreamerApplicationContextBase.init[kLive/_definst_]: Not licensed for HTTPOrigin mode: HTTPStreamerApplicationContextSanJoseStreamer - (WMSLogger.java:203)
[xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:x][ServerHandler.71][com.wowza.wms.logging.WMSLogger:log] WARN - HTTPStreamerApplicationContextBase.init[kLive/_definst_]: Not licensed for HTTPOrigin mode: HTTPStreamerApplicationContextCupertinoStreamer - (WMSLogger.java:203)
[xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:x][ServerHandler.71][com.wowza.wms.logging.WMSLogger:log] WARN - HTTPStreamerApplicationContextBase.init[kLive/_definst_]: Not licensed for HTTPOrigin mode: HTTPStreamerApplicationContextMPEGDashStreamer - (WMSLogger.java:203)
[xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:x][ServerHandler.71][com.wowza.wms.logging.WMSLogger:log] WARN - HTTPStreamerApplicationContextBase.init[kLive/_definst_]: Not licensed for HTTPOrigin mode: HTTPStreamerApplicationContextSmoothStreamer - (WMSLogger.java:203)
```

How to fix these errors.

Comment: How is this different from the question you asked 15 minutes ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500423/live-streaming-using-wowza-kaltura-fmle

Comment: @jurgemaister: Please check updated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500423/live-streaming-using-wowza-kaltura-fmle question......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are using a developer license, which does not include support for HTTPOrigin (according the [Wowza forums](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?35315-Wowza-Media-Server-4-developer-license-limitation)).  A paid license is required for that functionality.